# How do I use the 'scipy.integrate import quad' to solve this?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, physics

The electric field a distance z above the center of a segment of length 2L with uniform charge per length λ is vertical and its magnitude is:

[image]

Find an expression (integral) for the unitless quantity EL/kλ, where k =1/4πε0, and plot in Python EL/kλ vs. Z/L for values of Z/L from 0.5 to 10.0.

Comment: what have you tried so far? ie. how are you presenting the equation to sympy? how are you declaring your symbols? please include your code attempt as text so we can help you! we're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you have never used sympy before, I recommend first reading the [gotchas page](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html) (which especially deals with things like _assignment_ vs _equality_), then check out the [tutorial for calculus](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html)

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try that!

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to use the quad numerical integration because this is an explicitly solvable integral, so you get a formula for `E(z)`

[image]

Check out the calculations for errors because I did it by hand.